# Service Now integration with Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, servicenow

I want to integrate ServiceNow with Azure devops. For example if there is any incident created in service now it should create a bug/US in Azure devops. I found there are few services available from OpsHub but I want to use something which is provided by SNow or Azure.

Does anyone has done something similar and can help me here?

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.vss-services-servicenowchangerequestmanagement

Comment: Hi Sajeetharan, this plugin does onky help in change management and release approvals. What I need is something like this demo: https://youtu.be/IaInrrlHVrk

Comment: This blog(https://medium.com/@niegrejoh/integrating-servicenow-and-visual-studio-team-services-draft-1e9840f0fb06) can meet your demand but it  need to use Stamplay.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method to do so.

1. Go to SNOW portal.
2. Install Devops integration application (plugin)
3. Search > Connection & credential aliases > New > Name= “Azuredemo1” > submit
4. Search > credentials > new > basic Auth > name = “Azuredevops1” > username = “AzureDevOps1”
      For password = go to Azure DevOps and create new personal access token (top right corner select User settings > Personal access token)

   Copy and paste this token into SNOW credentials password tab.
   Submit

5. Snow portal > Search > connection > new > HTTP(s) > name = AzureDevOps1 > Credentials = select the one which you created in previous step (“Azuredevops1”) > connection alias = select the aliases you created before (“Azuredemo1”) > connection URL = go to Azure DevOps > org settings > copy URL from overview tab and past it in SNOW portal > submit
6. SNOW portal > search > Azure DevOps Instance > New > name = “AzureDemo1” > connection alias = select the aliases you created before (“AzureDemo1”) > Version = compatible one. > submit

   Now again go to Azure DevOps Instance dashboard and select AzureDemo1 (new instance that you just created) > click on Connect > once you do that your state will change to “Connected”

   Select create mapping > “map is created successfully”

   Select Discover Projects > under Azure DevOps Project tab you should see you project from Azure DevOps (ie :DCP)

   Now click on your project (DCP) > register webhooks > it will enable connection b/w Azure DevOps and SNOW

   Team integration settings > new > assignment group = “select your agile group” (you can create your own agile group from search > agile azure devops integration > create agile group) > Team = “select your azure devops team” (imported from Azure) > submit

Now you can create, delete or modify user story/feature from either Azure DevOps or SNOW portal, and they will be integrated automatically.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for.. Great step-by-step explanation Thank you !

Comment: I am trying to map a custom Work Item Type to ServiceNow (eg: "Demand" type instead of Epic/Feature and map it to Demand table).
It seems to work only one way from Azure to ServiceNow and not the other way. I can see Epics working properly. Any ideas why "Demand" is not triggering ?

Comment: Okay Answering my own ticket.. we have to add a new business rule to achieve this.
Ref : https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/rome-it-business-management/page/product/agile-azure-integration/task/create-business-rule-to-apply-custom-table-map.html

Answer (score 0):

> if there is any incident created in service now it should create a
>   bug/US in Azure devops.

As far as I know , there is no way provided by ServiceNow or azure devops to achieve this demand directly . Usually this is achieved through a third-party platform.

As the blog I mentioned in the comment said that you can create bugs in Visual Studio Team Services based on incidents getting reported in ServiceNow using Stamplay as the integration platform.You can also achieve this through other third-party platforms.

One way I can think of not going through a third-party platform is to write a script in azure devops, track the creation of incident on serviceNow, and then call the [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) of create a work item. This will be more cumbersome.

Comment: Thank you.. I feel thats the only last way possible to write some time trigger function and call rest APIs of Snow and create work items using VSTS rest API.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled on your request and felt compelled to respond. [Quick and easy off the shelf solution](https://www.quantumwhisper.com/servicenow-azure-devops-integration)... Allows you to send incidents or problems from ServiceNow to Azure DevOps --- complete with bidirectional updates. Built on Azure and [listed in AppSource](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en/product/web-apps/quantum-whisper.quantumwhisper?tab=Overview).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this using Azure Logic App, ServiceNow Rest Message with Business Rule trigger. This is one way. If you want bidirectional try using ServiceNow connection inside Azure Logic App.

[image]