# Integrating ServiceNow and Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, agile, servicenow

Is it possible to show incidents from ServiceNow on Azure DevOps board as work items and synchronize them bi-directionally? If possible, please explain how.

Comment: A suggestion is using Azure DevOps API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/

Answer (score 0):

In ServiceNow , it provides [Microsoft Azure DevOps Integration for Agile Development](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/orlando-it-business-management/page/product/agile-azure-integration/concept/agile-azure-integration-overview.html).If you update a record in Agile Development , you could directly use this Integration tool. It also supports  bidirectional synchronization.

On the other hand, you could need to use third-party tools to achieve this (e.g. Azure Logic App , [Zapier Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.services-zapier)). This is the general method.

Here is my example(Zapier) : `Get ServiceNow Record -> Create work item`

[image]

When it Get the Incident type record , it will trigger the Create work item step in Azure Devops.

The create work item steps is similar to using the Rest API to create work item.

To synchronize them bi-directionally, you could create other process to achieve this.

Here is [another ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57648544/service-now-integration-with-azure-devops) with the similar requirement.